# Guessing the color of a ball from the basket

Tags: probability

Let's say I have a basket with green and red balls. $70\%$ of the balls are green (let's call the fraction $f_g = 0.7$), the rest is red - $f_r=0.3$.

Now, suppose I take one ball from the basket and guess its color (without looking, of course). What's the probability that my guess was wrong?

Supposedly the answer is $f_g(1-f_g)+ f_r(1-f_r)$, but I cannot convince myself this is correct. How to describe the problem mathematically (sample space, etc.)?

Comment: I agree that $f_g$ is the probability of picking a green ball ($f_r$ - red). But why multiply it by $1-f_g$? How do I know that these events independent and I can multiply them?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read carefully enough. What are the probabilities of your guesses?

Comment: Do you guess randomly? I mean is your guess "blue" in 50% of times and red in other 50% of times? or knowing the fractions change the probability of your guesses?

Comment: I think the answer depends on the probabilities of you guessing green and guessing red. You haven't specified them. The given answer suggests that you guess, randomly, green 70% of the time and red 30% of the time.

Comment: @MickA I guess he/she must change the question to _What's the **minimum** probability that my guess was wrong?_ right?

Comment: @Abraham The min probability of guessing wrong would be when you guess green every time (because most balls are green), giving P(Wrong)=0.3.

Answer (score 3):

There are two situations :

1. You guess the color really randomly, i.e. you guess it is *green* for $50$% of times and you guess it is *red* for the other $50$% of times.
2. You guess efficiently to reduce the number of wrong guesses. In this situation, you must check to is if you guess *green* for $70$% of times and guess *red* for $30$% of times it is better or if you guess the color that we have more.

For both situations we have :

P(Wrong guess) = P(Guess is Green & You pick Red) + P(Guess is Red & You pick Green)

As your guess and the pick are independent, the probability of each part is multiply of its parameters, i.e. :

$P(Wrong_{Guess}) = P(Guess_{Green})* P(Pick_{Red})+P(Guess_{Red})*P(Pick_{Green})$

So for 1st situation :

$P(Wrong_{Guess})= 1/2 * 0.3 + 1/2* 0.7 = 0.5$

And for 2nd situation :

$P(Wrong_{Guess})= 0.7 * 0.3+ 0.3*0.7= 0.42 $

Look, $42$ % is greater than $30$%. So the best way to minimum the wrong guesses is to say Green for all the times, And in this situation, $P(Wrong_{Guess}) = 0.30$

Answer (score 2):

If 'guessing' means that there is a chance of $p_r$ that you guess red and a chance of $p_g$ (here $p_r+p_g=1$) that you guess green then the probability that your guess is wrong is: $$f_g\times p_r+f_r\times p_g$$

'Without looking' stands for independence of the two probabilities: the first concerns taking a ball, the second concerns making a guess.

It is up to yourself (as the one who guesses) how $\langle p_r,p_g\rangle$ looks like.

- In special case $p_r=p_g=\frac12$ this equals $f_g\times \frac12+f_r\times\frac12=0.5$.
- In special case $p_r=1\wedge p_g=0$ this equals $f_g=0.7$.
- In special case $p_r=0\wedge p_g=1$ this equals $f_r=0.3$.
- In special case $p_r=f_r\wedge p_g=f_g$ this equals $2f_gf_r=0.42$.
- In special case $p_r=f_g\wedge p_g=f_r$ this equals $f_g^2+f_r^2=0.58$.

Comment: I always thought the independence is just a mathematical concept, that says events $A$ and $B$ are independent iff $P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. We can't just guess that it holds by reading the description of our problem. Rather, we should prove it holds. I guess sometimes two events are SEEMINGLY independnet, and then it turns out they aren't. Or I don't understand independence...

Comment: The description of our problem provides the inspiration to make a mathematical model of the described reality.  Based on the description (and meeting what you call seemingly independence) we can conclude that independence is on its place as a part of that model.

Comment: So we need to take the fact that those events are independent as an axiom? We can't prove it, just like the validity of mathematical model of any informally stated problem in probability or any other mathematical theory.

Comment: Axioms are part of the theory and not assumptions that are made based on the description. Btw, do you 'believe' in independence here? If so then how would you *prove* it without preassuming and without referring to 'without looking'?

Comment: Yes, I should've used the word 'assumption', not 'axiom. We cannot prove it. As with every such problem in probability we do our best to come up with a 'reasonable' probabilistic model, but we cannot be sure if it's valid. Do you agree with me?

Comment: Well, if someone holds a colored ball and (without looking) guesses its color, then I don't see a problem in assuming that the color of that ball has no influence at all on this guessing (i.e. independence). Not sure? Let's be satisfied with 'almost sure' then :) Feel free to accept it or to reject it.

Comment: Last remark (maybe redundant): As the one holding the colored ball, you have knowledge of the probability that the ball is red (or green), but you have no knowledge of the color itself. The mentioned probability can influence your guess (e.g. if you are eager to make a correct guess then you choose for green, see my edit), but the color of the ball in your hands has no influence. That's my justification of independence.

Comment: Of course I agree they are independent. I'm just quite frustrated about probability in general - it's less 'certain' than other branches of mathematics, such as algebra. You are given a problem and try to figure out the sample space, outcomes favorable to given event etc. We cannot prove with absolute certainty that e.g. sample space is correct, best we can do is justify it and convince other people. We're using our intuition (intuitively true is very close to false, for me, because intuition often deceives us). The best example I can think of is the Monty hall paradox.

Comment: I understand your frustration. The main problem is in my view that in probability there is a strong link with reality. Probability will loose its value if that link gets lost. Characteristic for pure mathematics is the non-existence of that link. We can drop reality and construct whatever we like in e.g. algebra. There are matematicians who intensely like that link. It depends on what side you are on.

Comment: I'd say in algebra we still have a link with reality, but maybe not as direct as in case of probability. Pure mathematics exists for some reason, right? Eventually we use it for building new bridges, exploring the universe. The link is always there, but it's hidden. And always at this link things get less certain, whether it's probability or algebra.